# jquery next() element

Tags: jquery, list, jquery-selectors, toggle, parent

I have been looking through the archives but can't find a solution that works, I have a menu;

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <span><a class="doToggle"></a></span>
        <span class="toggleMe">stuff to hide and show</span>
    </li>
</ol>
```

I'm trying to toggle the second span when the anchor in the first span is clicked, I've tried;

```
$(this).parent().next().toggle();
```

Which I think should work, but I'm getting no response. any hints at where I'm going wrong?

Comment: 1: Please re-create your issue somewhere we can try it, for instance on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net). 2: This is a good situation to ***debug***. Simply put a break-point in the click event handler and check your selectors live. You can't fail.

Comment: The click is bound to the `<a>` or the `<span>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:D

http://jsfiddle.net/27xCe/

HTML:

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <span><a class="doToggle" href='#'>Click Me to Toggle</a></span>
        <span class="toggleMe">stuff to hide and show</span>
    </li>
</ol>​
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('.doToggle').click(function(e) {
        $('.toggleMe').toggle();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

or with `next()`:

```
$(function() {
    $('.doToggle').click(function(e) {
        $(this).parent().next().toggle();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/27xCe/1/

Thou shalt do some tutorials. http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials

​

Comment: thanks for the tuts link, not actually seen them before; I can't select by class as there are about 100 elements with the same class, hence tryign to use .next(), I'm not sure why the parent().next() wasn't working but moving the click event to the span rather than the anchor seemed to do the trick, not sure why, so;
    `<ol>
        <li>
            <span class="doToggle"><a>header</a></span>
            <span class="toggleMe">stuff to hide and show</span>
        </li>
    </ol>`

and jQuery:
    `$('.doToggle').bind('click', function() {
        $(this).next().toggle();
    });`

Comment: The reason that moving the click event to the span works in your case is because `this` in that callback function refers to an element of the "doToggle" class, which has to be a span. Only a span has a next element. A link does not have a next element since it is the sole element within its containing span.

Comment: Also, if you have a lot of span tags for which to assign events, you should consider using `delegate` instead of `bind` (http://www.alfajango.com/blog/the-difference-between-jquerys-bind-live-and-delegate/) because `bind` assigns an event node to every single matched element. That can be a golly lot of event nodes. D: D: D:

Comment: very interesting link, thanks for that! :) delegate also seems really handy for dynamic pages where dom elements may be added after the dom loads... cool!

Answer (score 0):

You got the wrong class in yr selector should be **toggleMe** not **doToggle**

http://jsfiddle.net/pK2FV/

or just remove the class selector and [do next](http://jsfiddle.net/jDR2k/)